# Getting 404 error in 'ngsw-worker' in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have added ngsw-worker and i am getting the below error

Error :

```
ngsw-worker.js:596 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Response not Ok (fetchAndCacheOnce): request for https://quill-dev.warburgpincus.com/assets/pdfjs/web/locale/locale.properties returned response 404 
    at LazyAssetGroup.<anonymous> (ngsw-worker.js:596)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (ngsw-worker.js:320)
```

Code that i have in ngsw-worker.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "Quill",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/favicon.ico", "/index.html", "/*.css", "/*.js"]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/assets/**"]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "urls": ["/valuations"],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3s"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not getting error in local but when i am deploying i am getting this error in the console